# openshift error unknown flag: --ssh-privatekey

Tags: openshift

I am trying to generate an secrete for a private repo on openshift. But I keep getting this error any idea why?

```
oc secrets new-sshauth sshsecret --ssh-privatekey=C:\Users\Name\.ssh\id_rsa
Error: unknown flag: --ssh-privatekey
See 'oc create --help' for usage.
```

according to the documentation
I need to do this

```
oc secrets new-sshauth sshsecret --ssh-privatekey=$HOME/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create ssh private key type secrets in OpenShift with this way

First generate your SSH key if you dont have one with the following command

```
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your_email@example.com"
```

Then you can create a secret in your openshift project with the following command

```
oc create secret generic <secret_name> \
    --from-file=ssh-privatekey=<path/to/ssh/private/key> \
    --type=kubernetes.io/ssh-auth -n <youropenshiftprojectname>
```